# Best way to automate Bad Words in a text box using web driver

Tags: c#, selenium, textbox, automation, webdriver

I have scenario where I have been given a list of 222 bad words that aren't supposed to be entered in all the textboxes.

How do I write my tests using c# and Webdriver?

I mean I know that I could loop through the words and enter them one by one and validate if the error message is displayed. But that would take long time. Please help me with this.

Comment: Using an automated test to do what you described would not, in fact, take a long time. What you've described is perhaps the best practice to verify that all your 'forbidden' words throw up the correct invalid response.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply Mark. Im new to this automation, hence my questions might seem unworthy to answer. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

If what your asking is to see if a textbox contains a bad word, you can use something like this:

```
var badWords = new List<String> {"bad", "bad1", "bad2"};
if (Regex.IsMatch("bad is the way to go", String.Format("({0})", String.Join("|", badWords.ToArray()))))
    Console.WriteLine(@"bad word");
```